# Create additional data when user get registered (ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a standard web application in ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 application, but I would like to create additional data for the user in a separate table when it get registered.

My steps:

- I have created the new table
- To get access to the "Identity as UI library" I have scaffolded identity UI, but I don't have any controller, so I have try to use the data context from "Register.cshtml.cs" file, but it needs a parameter in the constructor of the data context class.

In any case, use the context from the View is not recommended, so what is the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add additional column to `AspNetUsers` table to store additional data then update the `ApplicationUser` class as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName {get; set;}
}
```

Now run a new migration and update the database accordingly.

Now update the `InputModel` in the `Register.cshtml.cs` file as follows:

```
public class InputModel
{
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Then add the following code in the `Register` form in `Register.cshtml` file:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="Input.FullName"></label>
     <input asp-for="Input.FullName" class="form-control" />
     <span asp-validation-for="Input.FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Then in the `OnPostAsync` method in `Register.cshtml.cs` file:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { FulllName = Input.FullName, UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!. I suppose that update the current table is the best option.